# Misaligned close icon in newsletter preview dialog

Tags: discussion, bug, newsletter

I recently noticed a UI bug in the newsletter preview dialog

The close icon in the dialog of  newsletter preview overlapping the scrollbar

Please check the below Screen-Shot for the same issue

[image]